# What are additional system columns defined in greenplum?

Tags: greenplum

PostgreSQL has bunch of system columns defined at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html.

I am wondering what are the additional system columns defined by greenplum?

Is there any pointer of additional description of it?

Thanks,
Shin

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the system catalog can be found on docs.pivotal.io.  Here is the direct link to the current version:

http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4370/ref_guide/system_catalogs/catalog_ref.html#topic1

Comment: Thanks Jon. However, my question was  about 'system columns', those are the hidden columns with negative ids. Just saying that, I did a quick query:

`select distinct attname, attnum from pg_attribute where attnum < 0;`

So far `gp_segment_id` is only extra, but I cannot find official description of it.

Comment: That is the only hidden column I know of that is in Greenplum.  gp_segment_id is the unique id that corresponds to each segment.  It is documented in the Admin Guide for detecting table skew.